# Iron meteor's Route doesn't fire rendered event of the template

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

Here's my case. I'm building an template that should render a chart based on the some data that I can get by identifier.

The example that I will show here is the simplified version of my code that fully discribe my problem.

Here is my HTML:

```
<head>
  <title>example</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>

<template name="layout">
  <a href="/firstText">First text</a>
  <a href="/anotherText">Another text</a>
  {{> yield}} 
</template>

<template name="example">
  <span id="text">Basic Text</span>
</template>
```

And JavaScript:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Router.configure({
    layoutTemplate: 'layout'
  });

  Router.route('/:text', function() {
    this.render('example', {
      data: this.params.text
    });
  });

  Template.example.rendered = function() {
    $('#text').html(this.data);
  }
}
```

This code renders whatever you put in url into "p" tag. If you will go over the first link you will get the text "firstText". But after it if you will go over another link the text will be the same. The text will be changed if only will you reload the page.

That is because when you render the template via the iron:router's method this.render('template') the meteor creates and renders this template that cause the fire of the created and rendered events, but if you go to the other url from  the same router, the meteor doesn't destroy this template and recreates him, but just change the data. So the rendered event doesn't fire on change of the URL.

I can use only the rendered event and not the helpers because from helpers I can't get element with JQuery.

Now I'm using the solution where I'm wrap all the logic in rendered event into the Tracker.autorun() and use Session.set('text', this.params.text) in the router and Session.get('text') in the autorun function to rerender the text every time the URL will change. But this solution gives additional problems. And I think that Router's this.render('templateName') should fire the rendered event.

Could you please help me to make the first variant work without reactive data. Maybe there are some solutions that can truly rerender the template?

Comment: I have the same issue as well and asked that question a couple days ago. I haven't found anything to it other than registering a data context and pass everything through it.

Answer (score 0):

Meteor avoids re-rendering templates as much as possible and it is great because it makes code faster. The key here is to use reactivity. So you can write something like that in html:

```
<template name="example">
    <span id="text">{{text}}</span>
</template>
```

and in js file:

```
Template.example.helpers({
    text: function() {
        return this;
    }
});
```

You don't need rendered function for this and you don't need jQuery.

And if you want you can access element from helper with jQuery.
In rendered

```
Template.example.rendered = function() {
    this.rendered = true;
}
```

and then in helper

```
whateverHelper: function() {
    var tmpl = Template.instance;
    tmpl.rendered && tmpl.$('#something').makeFun();
}
```

Comment: As I said, I have a more complex example, where I need to render the chart to the canvas element. So the using of the jQuery is necessary.

Maybe exists the way where I can force destoying and re-rendering of the template?

Comment: Why can't you use jQuery in a helper as I showed you in example above? Template.instance is reactive so helper will rerun if the template data will change.